# Redis in python, how do you close the connection?

Tags: python, redis

https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

I know in ruby we use the quit() method. I can't find anything here for python

python:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.set('foo', 'bar')
print r.get('foo')
#r.close() doesn't work
```

ruby

```
require "redis"
redis = Redis.new
redis.set("mykey", "hello world")
puts redis.get("mykey")
redis.quit()
```

Comment: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py), `StrictRedis` doesn't implement `close` or `quit` methods.

Comment: is it okay that we don't close the connection, I don't think I understand connection to redis ...

Comment: @nevermind I see `r.client_kill`, but to find out, which client to kill, you have to list them by `r.client_list()`. Checking `$ netstat | grep 6379` I saw, the connection got into "closing" state. There is also `r.execute_command("QUIT")`. But I am still not sure, if it does, what you ask for.

Comment: do we need to kill it? can I safely use StrictRedis and not worry about the connection?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just use `redis.Redis`. It uses a connection pool under the hood, so you don't have to worry about managing at that level.

If you absolutely have to use a low level connection, you need to do the response handling that is normally done for you by `redis.Redis`.

Here's an example of executing a single command using the low level connection:

```
def execute_low_level(command, *args, **kwargs):
    connection = redis.Connection(**kwargs)
    try:
        connection.connect()
        connection.send_command(command, *args)

        response = connection.read_response()
        if command in redis.Redis.RESPONSE_CALLBACKS:
            return redis.Redis.RESPONSE_CALLBACKS[command](response)
        return response

    finally:
        del connection
```

Example usage:

```
response = execute_low_level(
        'HGET', 'redis:key', 'hash:key', host='localhost', port=6379)
```

But as I said before, `redis.Redis` is the way to go in 99.9% of cases.

Answer (score 18):

StrictRedis doesn't implement connection semantics itself, instead it uses a connection pool, which is available as a property of a StrictRedis instance: `S.connection_pool`. The connection_pool object has a `disconnect` method to force an immediate disconnect of all connections in the pool if necessary, however when your StrictRedis object goes out of scope, the individual connections in the pool all clean themselves up without your intervention (see redis/connection.py:392-396)

Comment: If I decide to go with Strict, do I need to worry about the connection?

Answer (score 10):

Use Redis connection pool. You don't need to explicitly close it.

```
import redis

pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

And can improve efficiency.

Comment: Redis uses a connection pool under the hood by default. [See the documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_features.html), or the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

you dont need worry about it when you use ConnectionPool.look at the source code:

```
def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
    "Execute a command and return a parsed response"
    pool = self.connection_pool
    command_name = args[0]
    connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
    try: 
        connection.send_command(*args)
        return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
    except (ConnectionError, TimeoutError) as e:
        connection.disconnect()
        if not connection.retry_on_timeout and isinstance(e, TimeoutError):
            raise
        connection.send_command(*args)
        return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
    finally:
        pool.release(connection)
```

finally,every connection will release to the pool no matter what you do, and it will assign to other client.

Comment: I read the `pool.release()` source code and I found the code as below:

```python                                             
     def release(self, connection):
        "Releases the connection back to the pool"
        self._checkpid()
        if connection.pid != self.pid:
            return
        self._in_use_connections.remove(connection)
        self._available_connections.append(connection)
```
My question is, when the `self.pid` is equal to `os.getpid` or when the process was killed, how close the connection automatic?